# Windows Store app - enumerate fonts

Tags: c#, xaml, fonts, windows-8, windows-store-apps

How do you enumerate all the installed fonts in a Windows Store app?

The `System.Windows.Media.Fonts` namespace is no longer available.

Comment: Do you mean it's not available in the particular project you are doing? I can't see any deprecation notices at MSDN. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fonts.aspx)

Comment: System.Globalization.Fonts namespace.  I doubt you'll like what you find there.  It does however get rid of the age-old misery of fonts only working in particular languages.

Comment: @NoxHarmonium there wouldn't be a deprecation notice, since WinRT is v1 (including the .NET Framework that runs on it).

Comment: @HansPassant yeah not what I want, it just shows a recommended (best) font the language. Doesn't like all fonts on the system.

Comment: What kind of application are you writing that requires the enumeration of fonts?

Comment: @NoxHarmonium a document editor - would be nice to allow users to change the fonts of documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use DirectWrite for this. See [DirectWrite font enumeration sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/DirectWrite-font-60e53e0b)

Answer (score 2):

I think that Microsoft encourage the use of standard fonts in WinRT/Windows Store Apps such as what is outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700394.aspx).

After having a look around it doesn't look like you can enumerate the fonts within the sandbox. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winappswithcsharp/thread/ef01d444-3d3d-40e5-825b-2973a40b8729) is an official Microsoft response to a similar question.